# AJAX function to Update A Page Value Without Refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp

I'm not familiar with AJAX, I need to update a value in a JSP page using a database table. Please help me to write the relevant AJAX part. What is currently I have done is like below, where the page only updates the value on refresh.

```
<script>
//Ajax code here
</script> 
<body>
    <%ResultSet rsplayer = db.selectQuery("select score, playerid from player where playerid = '100'"); while(rsplayer.next()){%>
    <h1><%out.print(rsplayer.getString("playerid"));%> = <%out.print(rsplayer.getString("score"));%></h1>
    <%}%>
</body>
```

Comment: lots and lots of tutorial on web to get started with

Comment: You can check the answer for [jQuery Ajax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19762001/how-to-submit-the-option-selected-from-drop-down-list-in-jsp-page-to-perform-a-m/19763284#19763284) may be useful for you. Let me know if you need any further help.